# "I will attend the party" or "I would attend the party"

Tags: word-choice

I'm confused between "will" and "would"

> - I **will/would** attend the party.

Which is the correct one?

Comment: Both are fully grammatical but have different meanings. You'll have to give some context for any further answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
I will attend the party.
```

This is like a promise. You will do it at a later time.

```
I would attend the party.
```

This is usually not said by itself. It is normally used like so:

```
I would attend the party, but I have a meeting that day.
```

Edit (below from [Gus](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/3877/gus)):

> It's worth mentioning explicitly: The 'would' form of response implies you want to attend but cannot, due to (whatever you say next, in this example, a meeting)

Comment: It's worth mentioning explicitly:  The 'would' form of response implies you want to attend but cannot, due to <whatever you say next, in this example, a meeting>.